# PHP Multiselect values postback

Tags: javascript, php, post, multi-select

I have two multiselect boxes and the user can move items from one box to other (accomplished using Javascript).  However, when I post the form, the POST value for the multiselect box where the user moves items to is empty.  If I select a few of them and then postback, I can see the ones I selected.

My question is....can I get all the values in a particular select box regardless of whether or not they're selected?

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="viewSelected" name="viewSelected[]">
//options go here
</select>
```

Thank you!
Jason

Comment: Are you saying that the values POST when you do it and not the user? Are you asking how to POST values from two selects where the second is populated by values from the first? Your question is a bit confusing, particularly the part where you say "I can see the ones I selected"

Comment: @Kisaragi Basically I need to get values from a multiselect box regardless of whether or not they're selected.  I need to get all of the options in a particular box.

Comment: Are the options actually selected when they're moved over? If not, they wouldn't get sent in the form submit.  Maybe add an on submit event listener that sets all options in the multiselect as selected.

Comment: You know the values already beforehand, you can store them in an array or use javascript/jquery and append to the form the values.

Comment: "multiselect box regardless of whether or not they're selected", it would be easier just to set them to selected before submitting.

Comment: @Anthony Agreed - this approach makes the most sense.  I'll see if I can figure out the script to select them all when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about dependable dropdown list. Am i right?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  I have two multiselect boxes presented to the user.  The box on the left has a list of options and there are buttons for them to select options and move them to the box on the right.  I've got all that working no issue with JS but now what I need is to get all of the values in the box on the right (name=viewOptions) when the page is posted back regardless of whether they're selected or not.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To get `option` values and text you can loop through them

```
$('select option').each(function(){
    let value = $(this).attr('value');
    let text = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

To print according to the value of first box, you need to give a class to the first box. Every time after clicking the box a unique id will be generated. 
According to that, you can get data in the second box by using Ajax function